# Bouncycastle for JDK 1.7 and PKCS libraries

Tags: maven, bouncycastle

I am trying to locate the PKCS libraries (pkcs10 CSR calls) of the Bouncycastle for JDK 1.7. I came across [the official Bouncycastle maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle) and got totally confused because of the amount of different versions. I have specially looked for `bcmail.jar` (and fount one for JDK 1.5) but did not found any for JDK 1.7.

Can somebody tell me which jar should I use and how can I integrate maven dependency for Bouncycastle in my `pom.xml`, so that this references the latest bouncycastle release?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have used Bouncycastle version 1.45 in a Java 1.7 project without problems.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk16</artifactId>
    <version>1.45</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Iam not quiet sure if it does. But do try it and see if you won't get the dependencies you want or otherwise check their website here: http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html

Answer (score 0):

Current BC releases use jdk1.5 compliance, see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.55 (august 2016)