# BouncyCastle jars giving SHA1 Digest Error for JDK 1.7

Tags: weblogic, java-7, bouncycastle, sign

For my project, I have to digitally sign a string and I am using bouncycastle jars for the same. The environment Details are as follows.

> Weblogic 12c JSF, Primefaces Java Version : 1.7.0_45 BC Jars :
>   bcmail-jdk15on-152.jar, bcpkix-jdk15on-152.jar,
>   bcprov-ext-jdk15on-152.jar, bcprov-jdk15on-152.jar

Alternatively I have used bcprov-jdk16-1.45.jar and bcmail-jdk16-1.45.jar as well but the result is same. The Error I am getting is,

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: SHA1WithRSAEncryption, provider: BC, class: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKDigestSignature$SHA1WithRSAEncryption)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1262) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:206) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.security.Signature.getInstance(Signature.java:355) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at DigiSigner.sign(DigiSigner.java:185) [DigiSigner.class:?]
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: SHA1 digest error for org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/JDKDigestSignature$SHA1WithRSAEncryption.class
    at sun.security.util.ManifestEntryVerifier.verify(ManifestEntryVerifier.java:220) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:229) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:216) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier$VerifierStream.read(JarVerifier.java:471) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.misc.Resource.getBytes(Resource.java:124) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:444) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1279) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1237) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    ... 44 more
```

The Code for DigiSigner.java is

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.SignatureException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateEncodingException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;

import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaCertStore;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSException;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSProcessableByteArray;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedData;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedDataGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSTypedData;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.ContentSigner;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.util.Store;

import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;


@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class DigiSigner {
    private String certFilePath = null;
    private String pfxFilename = null;
    private String jksFilename = null;
    private String certPassword = null;
    private char[] certPasswordArr = null;
    private KeyStore keystore = null;
    CMSSignedDataGenerator sgen = null;


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public DigiSigner(String certificatePrefix) throws IBException{
        ConfigManager config = ConfigManager.getConfigManager();
        this.certFilePath = "D:/Chintan/cert_files";
        this.pfxFilename = "chintan.pfx";
        this.jksFilename = "chintan.jks";
        this.certPassword = "abc123";

        certPasswordArr = certPassword.toCharArray();

        try{
            this.keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
            File jksFile = new File(certFilePath + "/" + jksFilename);
            if(!jksFile.exists()){
                this.createJKS();
            }
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(certFilePath + "/" + jksFilename);
            keystore.load(input, certPasswordArr);

        }
        catch(KeyStoreException e){
            e.printStacktrace();
        } 
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStacktrace();
        } 
        catch (CertificateException e) {
            e.printStacktrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStacktrace();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public String sign(String dataToSign) throws IBException{
        String signedData = null;
        try {
            byte[] dataToSignArr = dataToSign.getBytes();
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
            Enumeration e = keystore.aliases();
            String alias = "";
            if(e != null){
                while(e.hasMoreElements()){
                    String  n = (String)e.nextElement();
                    if (keystore.isKeyEntry(n)){
                        alias = n;
                    }
                }
            }
            PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey(alias, certPasswordArr);
            Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1WithRSA", "BC");
            signature.initSign(privateKey);
            signature.update(dataToSignArr);

            //Build CMS
            X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) this.keystore.getCertificate(alias);
            List certList = new ArrayList();
            CMSTypedData msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray(signature.sign());
            certList.add(cert);
            Store certs = new JcaCertStore(certList);
            CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
            ContentSigner sha1Signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA").setProvider("BC").build(privateKey);
            gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build()).build(sha1Signer, cert));
            gen.addCertificates(certs);
            CMSSignedData sigData = gen.generate(msg, false);
            BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
            signedData = encoder.encode((byte[]) sigData.getSignedContent().getContent());
            System.out.println("Signature is : " + signedData);     
        }
        catch(KeyStoreException e){
            e.printStacktrace();
        } 
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStacktrace();
        }
        catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            e.printStacktrace();
        }
        catch (CMSException e) {
            e.printStacktrace();
        }
        catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
            e.printStacktrace();
        } 
        catch (SignatureException e) {
            e.printStacktrace();
        }
        catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStacktrace();
        }
        catch (CertificateEncodingException e) {
            e.printStacktrace();
        }
        catch (OperatorCreationException e) {
            e.printStacktrace();
        } 
        return signedData;
    }

    public void createJKS() throws IBException{
        try{
            File fileIn = new File(certFilePath + "/" + pfxFilename);
            File fileOut = new File(certFilePath + "/" + jksFilename);

            if(!fileIn.canRead()){
                throw new IBException("Unable to access input keystore: " + fileIn.getPath());
            }
            if(fileOut.exists() && !fileOut.canWrite()){
                throw new IBException("Output file is not writable: " + fileOut.getPath());
            }

            KeyStore kspkcs12 = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            KeyStore ksjks = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");

            char inphrase[] = certPassword.toCharArray();
            char outphrase[] = certPassword.toCharArray();


            kspkcs12.load(new FileInputStream(fileIn), inphrase);
            ksjks.load(fileOut.exists() ? ((java.io.InputStream) (new FileInputStream(fileOut))) : null, outphrase);
            Enumeration eAliases = kspkcs12.aliases();
            do{
                if(!eAliases.hasMoreElements())
                    break;
                String strAlias = (String)eAliases.nextElement();
                if(kspkcs12.isKeyEntry(strAlias))
                {
                    java.security.Key key = kspkcs12.getKey(strAlias, inphrase);
                    Certificate chain[] = kspkcs12.getCertificateChain(strAlias);
                    ksjks.setKeyEntry(strAlias, key, outphrase, chain);
                }
            } 
            while(true);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileOut);
            ksjks.store(out, outphrase);
            out.close();
        }
        catch(KeyStoreException e){
            e.printStacktrace();
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStacktrace();
        } 
        catch (CertificateException e) {
            e.printStacktrace();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStacktrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStacktrace();
        }
        catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
            e.printStacktrace();
        } 
        System.out.println("Java Key Store created successfully");
    }
}
```

I Referred this link : [Bouncycastle for JDK 1.7 and PKCS libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23246027/bouncycastle-for-jdk-1-7-and-pkcs-libraries) - But well, it's not working for me.

The error is on this line : Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1WithRSA", "BC");

Answer (score 1):

As [mentioned here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3651558?start=0&tstart=0), Weblogic contains an invalid *bcprov-jdk16-1.45.jar*

Try to verify `MW_HOME/oracle_common/modules/bcprov-jdk16-1.45.jar` with *jarsigner* utility:

```
jarsigner -verify bcprov-jdk16-1.45.jar
```

The SecurityException is thrown:

```
jarsigner: java.lang.SecurityException: SHA1 digest error for org/bouncycastle/jce/ECKeyUtil$UnexpectedException.class
```

The file differs from the one in the [Maven Repository](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk16/1.45/), that passes verification successfully.

Answer (score 0):

A [list of related signature algorithms](https://github.com/boeboe/be.boeboe.spongycastle/blob/master/src/be/boeboe/spongycastle/chapter1/ListBCCapabilities.java) supported by *Bouncycastle*:

```
SHA1withRSA
SHA1withRSA/ISO9796-2
SHA1withRSA/PSS
SHA1withRSA/X9.31
SHA1withRSAEncryption
SHA1withRSAandMGF1
```

Therefore, it should work!

I guess that something is wrong with your `Java classpath`. You might be mixing incompatible *Bouncycastle* Jar files as explained [here](https://github.com/macourtney/Dark-Exchange/issues/1).

You are referencing  `bcprov-ext-jdk15on-152.jar` **and** `bcprov-jdk15on-152.jar`. But only one of these should be taken. Leave out the `ext` version.